# swiper slider сжимает блоки на мобильной версии

Tags: css, jquery, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообщем swiper slider сжимает блоки, (дефолтные слайды также сжимает) как от этого можно избавиться?

Должно быть так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, возможно кому поможет

Для начала слайдам (картинкам в частности) в свойствах css укажите ширину `min-width` к примеру, потом самое главное)

В параметрах Swiper slider можно указать параметры показа слайдов, т.е обрезать их как на втором скрине вопроса

Например:
`slidesPerView: 1.5` будет показывать 1 слайд целиком, а второй наполовину.

Воспользуйтесь брекпойнтами

Получилось так:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".admins_slider", {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  loop: true,
  passiveListeners: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  breakpoints: {
    320:{
      slidesPerView: 1.2,
      loop: false,
      passiveListeners: false,
    },
    720:{
      slidesPerView: 4,
      loop: true,
      passiveListeners: true,
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Вообще для начала надо бы документацию почитать. Там бы помимо `breakpoints` узнали бы о `slidesPerView: 'auto'`, ну и для особо ленивых, на сайте Swiper'а, существует страница с [демо](https://swiperjs.com/demos), где практически все свойства отображаются, а ещё недавно сделали [конструктор](https://studio.swiperjs.com/).